# SendKeys.Send() does not send or react as I expect

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

I have a problem using `Sendkeys.Send` in my C# application and I really cannot understand why. When using it then it does not send what I expect to the active application. I am using it together with the global hotkey manager, https://github.com/thomaslevesque/NHotkey

I have created this simple PoC that, for my part at least, will be able to reproduce my problem. Just launch *Wordpad* and press the hotkey, `ALT + O`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NHotkey.WindowsForms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Convert string to keys
            string hotkey = "Alt + O";
            KeysConverter cvt;
            Keys key;
            cvt = new KeysConverter();
            key = (Keys)cvt.ConvertFrom(hotkey);

            // Setup the hotkey
            HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("MyID", key, HotkeyAction);

            // Copy some text to the clipboard that I want to paste to the active application
            Clipboard.SetText("My String");
        }

        private void HotkeyAction(object sender, NHotkey.HotkeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Pressed the hotkey");
            SendKeys.Send("^v");
//            SendKeys.Send("Test string");
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }    
}
```

When I do this in *Wordpad*, then instead of pasting the clipboard (`^v` equals `CTRL + V`) then it tries to "Paste Special":

[image]

Even if I do the most simple thing and then just put some text in `SendKeys.Send`, then it seems to be messing with the menus in *Wordpad*? `SendKeys.SendWait` is not any different.

I have been trying to figure this out for quite some time now but I simply do not understand why it does that. Basically, I need to paste the clipboard on a hotkey though it doesn't need to be with this exact method so if anyone knows another way of doing it then I would appreciate some hints.

---

**MY IMPLEMENTED SOLUTION**

Based on the accepted answer then I did change my implementation slightly as I could not get it working with just a timer. I may have missed something(?) but this is working.

In basic then I change focus to my application as soon as the hotkey is detected, to avoid conflict with modifier keys (`ALT` etc) in the active application. I then create an invisible form and when I detect a `KeyUp` event, then I check for modifier keys and if none is pressed down then I enable a timer and immediately switch focus back to the originating application. After 50ms the clipboard will be pasted to the active application.

Something like this:

```
// Somewhere else in code but nice to know
// IntPtr activeApp = GetForegroundWindow(); // get HWnd for active application
// SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle); // switch to my application

private System.Timers.Timer timerPasteOnHotkey = new System.Timers.Timer();

// Main
public PasteOnHotkey()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Define the timer
    timerPasteOnHotkey.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    timerPasteOnHotkey.Interval = 50;
    timerPasteOnHotkey.Enabled = false;

    // Make the form invisble
    this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
    this.Opacity = 0.0;
}

private void PasteOnHotkey_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if modifier keys are pressed
    bool isShift = e.Shift;
    bool isAlt = e.Alt;
    bool isControl = e.Control;

    // Proceed if no modifier keys are pressed down
    if (!isShift && !isAlt && !isControl)
    {
        Hide();

        // Start the timer and change focus to the active application
        timerPasteOnHotkey.Enabled = true;
        SetForegroundWindow(activeApp);
    }
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timerPasteOnHotkey.Enabled = false;
    SendKeys.SendWait("^v"); // send "CTRL + v" (paste from clipboard)
}
```

Comment: Most likely because you’re holding the alt key at the same time, Wordpad takes that into account. What if you add a delay of a second before sending keypresses and make sure the alt hasn’t opened the menus?

Comment: Tested it out and if you wil provide an answer then I will accept it. So simple and yet I did not think of this at all! :-) I think a 250ms delay would be enough for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `SendKeys.Send` in a response to a key press then the keys you send may be combined with the physical keys you’re holding at that moment. In this case you’re holding Alt, so Wordpad assumes you pressed Alt-Ctrl-V instead of just Ctrl-V. Also Alt opens menu, so sending other keys may relate to hotkeys there.

Adding a delay will remove this issue, and usually when sending key presses it would be done as not relating to other key presses so it won’t be a problem.